# Extract exact match from DF using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a DF(Text) where I need to extract exactly month and year from Text containing only month/year but when I apply this formula it extracts month/year from dd/month/year also which I don't want.

e.g.

> Text1 -5/24/1990 CPT Code: 90792: With medical services
>
> Text2 - Since 10/2014: Fatigued, more forgetful, impaired dexterity on her left hand. MRI reveals an approximately 4.2cm x 3.3cm x 2.5cm right parietal enhancing mass with surrounding edema.

I need to extract only `10/2014` from DF but when I apply this formula it extracts `24/1990` and `10/2014` both.

I also need to extract only year from a text from the same DF when there is only year mentioned in the text.

Formula:

```
df['Text'].str.extractall(r'((?P<Month>\d{1,2})\/(?P<Year>\d{4}))')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
((?<!\d/)(?<!\d)(?P<Month>\d{1,2})\/(?P<Year>\d{4}))
```

As seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/gAKMvH/1)

**Note:** This was the most comprehensive solution, but there are methods much easier than this, like checking for a space before the extractable date

## Explanation:

`(?<!)` is a negative lookbehind in regex, which ensures that the match is not preceded by something. Here, I've made sure the match isn't preceded by a number or a number followed by a slash

Comment: Thanks my issue is resolved.Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @AnandJyesth If any answer has solved your question, don't forget to accept it as the correct answer, because it can easily help other people with similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `(?<!\/|\d)\d{1,2}\/\d\d\d\d(?!\/|\d)`

Explanation:

`(?<!\/|\d)` - negative lookbehind: assert that what preceeds is not `/` or `\d` (any digit)

`\d{1,2}` - match one or two digits

`\/` - match `/` literally

`\d\d\d\d` - match four digits

`(?!\/|\d)` - negative lookahead: assert that what follows is not `/` or `\d` (any digit)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tIlCbz/1)

Comment: The pattern matches 2 digits for the month instead of `\d{1,2}` I think you could also write it using a character class `(?<![/\d])(?P<Month>\d{1,2})/(?P<Year>\d{4})(?![/\d])` https://regex101.com/r/6LVjv5/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks, corrected. You're right with classes and it was my initial idea, but lookarounds give more flexibility.

Comment: There are three issues with this solution: 1) it won't work with current OP code 2) It won't work if there is an expected match before `/`, 3) it won't extract just a year if there is a year without month.

Comment: Thanks my issue is resolved.Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @AnandJyesth You should accept one of the answers or post your own, so in the future someone can benefit from this question.